# Accepting and processing user input in Scheme

Tags: user-interface, input, scheme, racket

I am using DrRacket, version 6.4, English to create a small application in Scheme.

In my application I would like to act upon a simple roll again dialog.

This is what I have so far. 
[FYI-when I set roll-number = 0 my program will exit later on in code.]

```
(begin
    (display "Would you like to roll again?(Y/N)\n")
    (if(not (equal? (read) "Y"))
        (begin
            (set! roll-number 0)
        )
        (display "")
        )
)
```

Right now; the roll-number variable is set to 0 no mater how I answer the  "Would you like to roll again?(Y/N)" question.

What exactly is the read returning and how would I go about comparing the return value to something so my program can make the correct decision?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
(equal? (read) 'Y)
```

Read is returning a *symbol*, not a string.

Comment: @merkman I'm glad that helped :) . As a side note, if you really-really have to input/process a _string_, then type it at the prompt using double quotes: `"Y"`